# IE 8 and the UPS Thermal Printer ActiveX Control

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, ups

Does anyone have a solution for getting the UPS labels to print from a custom web page (not the UPS test site) on a UPS thermal printer? In Firefox and Chrome it will print two labels at a time, but in IE 8 I can't get it to print using either the  or  tags. I have the type set to "application/epl2" but that's not working.

If I return the label as a document with the epl2 extension and associate that extension with Internet Explorer then it will print the label, but this is clearly not an ideal solution since it requires so much from the user side.

Does anyone have experience with this that could help? I'd really appreciate any pointers to get this thing working.